# Debug code on development vs master

Tags: git, merge, repository

I feel have inconsistent workflow with Git and try to figure out how to tweek this a bit.
The basic problem is with my `development` branch vs `master` branch concernig DEBUG code. Suppose I have file:

```
/* release code */
...
/* debug code on development - every time removed before merge to master */
...
/* release code */
```

I start with this trunks:

```
<R1><--<R2><--<R3>                                master

<c1><--<c2><--<c3><--<c4>                         development
```

I realized its time for release. I need to merge --no-ff to `master` branch. But I want to keep my DEBUG code. Because of that I create a temporary brach `prepare-R4` on `development`.

```
<R1><--<R2><--<R3>                                master

                         <r41><--<r42>            prepare-R4
                        /
<c1><--<c2><--<c3><--<c4>                         development
```

After removing DEBUG code I merge --no-ff to `master`.

```
<R1><--<R2><--<R3><-------------------<R4>        master
                                      /
                         <r41><--<r42>            prepare-R4
                        /
<c1><--<c2><--<c3><--<c4>                         development
```

Suppose now I have small fix on master called `hotfix-my-code` (`code` is just a random non working feature). I don't want to apply on `development`, because I need always run new `prepare-RX` to migrate to `master`. This is how I do that:

```
                                         <a1>        hotfix-my-code
                                        /    \
<R1><--<R2><--<R3><-------------------<R4><--<R41>   master
                                      /
                         <r41><--<r42>               prepare-R4
                        /
<c1><--<c2><--<c3><--<c4>                            development
```

Now I should merge this to `development` to populate `<a1>`. Right? But there is my DEBUG code which I want to keep forever on `development`! If I merge it will be removed.

```
                                         <a1>              hotfix
                                        /    \
<R1><--<R2><--<R3><-------------------<R4><--<R41>         master
                                      /          \
                         <r41><--<r42>            \        prepare-R4
                        /                          \
<c1><--<c2><--<c3><--<c4><-------------------------<c5>    development
```

Another problem, every time I need to release run my new branch `prepare-RX` which generates removing always the same DEBUG code (or some more DEBUG code if it was extended by time). It is annoying. Can I optimize this flow somehow?

```
<R3><-------------------<R4><--<R41><---------------------<R5>  master
                         /        \                       /
                        /          \          <r41><--<r42>     prepare-R5
           <r41><--<r42>            \        /                  prepare-R4
          /                          \      /
<c3><--<c4><-------------------------<c5><c6>                   development
```

Comment: What is the "DEBUG" code? You mean "unit and integration tests"? xD

Comment: Hmm. It is something which is not for release... But now I think this are unfinished features / experiments as well.

Comment: I should add my approach is basing on this article http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ but is simplified.

Comment: :D Thank you. I like that too. Hope some day I can use some automatic tool for that. Feel free to upvote a question.